# django limit number of items that can be created by user - user packages

Tags: python, django

I hope I typed my question title correctly. I have examined lots of posts but couldn't exactly find what I need.

You know, for some listing websites like *real estates* or *product selling sites* there are some user packages: **Free Member** (for 1 item), **Silver Member** (for 3 items) and **Gold Member**(for 10) items.. Each type of user can create limited amount of items which are assigned for that package. They are not allowed to create more than the package allows.

These packages might contain other specs. as well, like Free (3 photos), Silver (5 photos), Gold (10 photos) etc.

How to do this "user - packages things" with django? How should I look for it?

Answer (score 4):

This sort of thing is best implemented at the database level. Using constraints as supported by many databases including Postgresql. The second best option is still at the database level but using triggers instead (for example on mysql). The last resort is to do this by over riding the save method in your model.

This is a  sort of a poor man's BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
   if MyModel.objects.filter(user_profile=self.user_profile).count() < X:
      return super(MyModel,self).save(*args,**kwargs)

   raise ValidationError("Too many records mate")
```

Note that to make it foolproof you would have to wrap the whole thing in transactions. Alternatively, you can save the object, then do the count, delete and raise an exception if the number has been exceeded.

After all this has been done, it's quite possible for someone to muck things up by inserting a record using the DB shell - which can be avoided by the user of triggers or contraints as already mentioned.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer dear @e4c5 and sorry for my late reply. I have not tried it yet but it gave me the main idea.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any modules that do this for you out of the box (someone else might be though), but it should be relatively easy to implement with something like this:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.db import models

class BlogPost(models.Model):
    user_profile = models.ForeignKey('module.UserProfile')

    def clean(self):
        numPosts = BlogPost.objects.filter(user_profile=self.user_profile).count()
        if numPosts > self.user_profile.max_posts:
            raise ValidationError("Your user plan does not support more than {} posts".format(numPosts))
```

This assumes you have a `UserProfile` model somewhere that stores the maximum number of posts for a user. It'll likely look different in your application, so use this only to get you started ...

Note that by overriding the `clean()` method (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean) you can make use of Django's validation errors, but it will not be executed if you call `instance.save()` manually somewhere in your code base. For that you'd also need to add logic to the `save()` method.

Comment: thanks @Geotob. I guess I got the main point here. I will try and I hope I will be able to succeed it! (sorry for my late reply)